# why isn't the text visible in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I use a very cool template which the creator was nice enough to make available for free. However I have some problems with it in IE 8 - the text is not visible.
I tried to change the css, to see what would happen if I take one thing out and so but I didn't get anywhere... Can somebody more experienced tell me which property is screwing everyting up? I tried to fix it for 3 hours and didn't get anywhere. You can see the site here: http://luiszuno.com/themes/watercolor/spring/

The menu or any of the text is not visible in IE...

If I could I would point you to a specific code block, but I was not able to isolate it..
Thank you

Comment: before I look at this I just want to make sure (sorry if this is a dumb question) you are familiar with the IE console right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site is using Cufon to render those texts that are not showing up. I've had problem with Cufon in IE9 in general. Actually I see the text in IE8 on that site but not IE9.

Try adding the following in your page to see if it fixes it:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]> <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.set('engine', 'canvas'); </script> <![endif]-->
```

In addition here's some info on IE9 and Cufon:

http://blog.ninanet.com/2011/04/29/cufon-and-ie9

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
```

add that in the head section and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

All of your navigation items are in `<canvas>` tags, which are not supported in IE 8 and earlier